# how can I use Kappa for assessing methods which create Commission error?

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy, cohens-kappa

I applied 4 methods to detect trees in a forest.
the reference number of tree is 1668.

method #1:
correctly detected (True Positive) = 943;
not detected or Omission error (False Negative) = 725;
doesn’t exist or Commission error (False Positive) = 469

method #2:
correctly detected (True Positive) = 1034;
not detected or Omission error (False Negative) = 634;
doesn’t exist or Commission error (False Positive) =578

method #3:
correctly detected (True Positive) = 983;
not detected or Omission error (False Negative) = 685;
doesn’t exist or Commission error (False Positive) =525

method #4:
correctly detected (True Positive) = 875;
not detected or Omission error (False Negative) = 793;
doesn’t exist or Commission error (False Positive) =131

I want to statistically know that which one significantly better by considering both commission and omission errors.

So, how can I use Kappa (or any other validations) in this case which I have #tree or #NotTree (1 class) and commission  error?

Thanks